# Vertically centering image in inline-block column

Tags: html, css

I have two columns - One with 70% and one with 30% width. With content, the height of the 70% div is a lot larger then the image that is in the 30% div. I am trying to vertically center the 30% div but `vertical-align` isn't working as I intended it.

Does anyone know how I could center the 30% div with it's parent?

### Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swqe6fet/)

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:50px;">
  <div class="col-2-70-30-grid">
    <div class="col-70">
      <h1>Random Text</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec ante ligula. Mauris accumsan mollis fringilla. Cras sed libero ac magna mollis malesuada quis a felis. Sed in justo non elit rutrum maximus. Integer vulputate velit sed elit
        porta, id placerat libero tincidunt. Sed pretium vehicula nisl, pharetra euismod sapien. Sed blandit eros purus, sed pulvinar nisl viverra quis. Nunc scelerisque at nisi eu viverra. Donec suscipit molestie elit in tempor. Quisque interdum felis
        a luctus euismod.</p>

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus viverra euismod eros, eu varius risus ullamcorper eu. Sed quis orci in nunc varius condimentum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-30">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.col-2-70-30-grid { font-size:0;width:100%; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 { border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;width:70%;font-size:24px;padding:10px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 h1 { color:#7DC246;font-weight:700;font-size:32px;line-height:60px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 p { font-size:16px;color:#5f6a7d;line-height:26px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-30 { border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:30%;font-size:24px; }
```

Comment: Tip: Are you annoyed by the white space under the image? Use `display: block` for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best for simplicity and maintainability to use flexbox here.

**Live Demo:**

```css
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.col-2-70-30-grid { font-size:0;width:100%; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 { border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;width:70%;font-size:24px;padding:10px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 h1 { color:#7DC246;font-weight:700;font-size:32px;line-height:60px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 p { font-size:16px;color:#5f6a7d;line-height:26px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-30 { border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;width:30%;font-size:24px; }

.col-2-70-30-grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:50px;">
  <div class="col-2-70-30-grid">
    <div class="col-70">
      <h1>Random Text</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec ante ligula. Mauris accumsan mollis fringilla. Cras sed libero ac magna mollis malesuada quis a felis. Sed in justo non elit rutrum maximus. Integer vulputate velit sed elit
        porta, id placerat libero tincidunt. Sed pretium vehicula nisl, pharetra euismod sapien. Sed blandit eros purus, sed pulvinar nisl viverra quis. Nunc scelerisque at nisi eu viverra. Donec suscipit molestie elit in tempor. Quisque interdum felis
        a luctus euismod.</p>

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus viverra euismod eros, eu varius risus ullamcorper eu. Sed quis orci in nunc varius condimentum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-30">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/vogxr5Lb/

Comment: I'd rather not use flex box but I appreciate the answer. I'd prefer internet explorer 8/9 support.

Comment: @bryan I pity the users of yours who are stuck with IE9, but I've added an answer that does not use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that uses `display: table` and `display: table-cell` instead of flexbox.

**Live Demo:**

```css
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.col-2-70-30-grid { font-size:0;width:100%; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 { border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;width:70%;font-size:24px;padding:10px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 h1 { color:#7DC246;font-weight:700;font-size:32px;line-height:60px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-70 p { font-size:16px;color:#5f6a7d;line-height:26px; }
.col-2-70-30-grid .col-30 { border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;width:30%;font-size:24px; }

.col-2-70-30-grid {
  display: table;
}

.col-2-70-30-grid > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:50px;">
  <div class="col-2-70-30-grid">
    <div class="col-70">
      <h1>Random Text</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec ante ligula. Mauris accumsan mollis fringilla. Cras sed libero ac magna mollis malesuada quis a felis. Sed in justo non elit rutrum maximus. Integer vulputate velit sed elit
        porta, id placerat libero tincidunt. Sed pretium vehicula nisl, pharetra euismod sapien. Sed blandit eros purus, sed pulvinar nisl viverra quis. Nunc scelerisque at nisi eu viverra. Donec suscipit molestie elit in tempor. Quisque interdum felis
        a luctus euismod.</p>

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus viverra euismod eros, eu varius risus ullamcorper eu. Sed quis orci in nunc varius condimentum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-30">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/vogxr5Lb/1/

Comment: Thank you for this. I selected the flex box one as the answer since it's not legacy but please keep this one for other people.